# Where to ask question: 'choose host-machine for many android-emulators"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need to run many (about 10) android emulators (android virtual devices) on a 1 host machine. 
AVDs should be optimized to run graphic applications (video rendering, games).
What computing power is recommended? Processor? Video card? Ram? What OS fits best?

Comment: I'd suggest you learn how to write a clear question before you start wondering where to ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is - I'm not *sure*.

I'd break down your question into three parts

> We have a complex app with many interconnection.

Tells me nothing. Physical or "network"  connections?

> In emulators (AVDs android virtual devices) on different Android APIs

Arm or x86 android? Does generic android VMs work for you?

> Though about this. But if i need to run iOS? There are no variants except iMac with OSX or usual pc with ha****thosh.

Tricky - the emulator side might be a question for s[oftware recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). In fact, a more specific question on android emulators for your needs or android test frameworks would be a good idea.

As for the actual host machine - *much* more detail (including the results of the previous questions I suggested) would make [hardware recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) a possible home for it.

Things like what type/how many VMs and so in would be essential.

So, flesh it out, break it up.